# Retrieve data from variable results view

Tags: c#, arrays, html-agility-pack

I am using the `htmlAgilityPack` to retrieve data from a table as so-

```
var text = from x in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                   where x.Name == "p" && x.Attributes.Contains("class")
                   where x.Attributes["class"].Value == "cut"
                   select x.InnerText;
```

On debugging I can access the `Results View` which shows all the parsed data I need to access. However I cannot figure out how to `return` the data array that has been parsed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are returning is a simple string back to the variable text,so there is nothing to iterate or view the results(ResultsView).Remember you are not returning a IEnumerable object to use ResultViews.

I think you need this

```
var Result= from x in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                   where x.Name == "p" && x.Attributes.Contains("class")
                   where x.Attributes["class"].Value == "cut"

foreach(var Item in Result){
//Access Item here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If,not able to `return` is only your problem then I believe it's quite simple..

```
var text=from x in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                       where x.Name == "p" && x.Attributes.Contains("class")
                       where x.Attributes["class"].Value == "cut"
                       select x.InnerText;
    //As the  above  query returns string,so you can check the result here..
    Label1.text=text.ToString()
```